# Возможно через js узнать цвет пикселя?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Здравствуйте! Возможно на стороне клиента узнать цвет пикселя?
На странице  снизу справа iframe показывающий разную рекламу по таргету. Мне интересно знать цвет рекламы и записать его юзеру в куки.
Подскажите, возможно такое?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/

Comment: @SultanovShamil, вам стоит оформить его в виде полноценного ответа с пояснениями, помните Вы не только отвечаете на текущий вопрос, но и помогаете с решением людям, которые будут искать подобную информацию в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Из iframe, на домене, вне вашего контроля, context не получить, цвет тоже.

Дело в безопасности, иначе можно было бы получать приватную информацию, открыв сайт на котором залогинен юзер в iframe, что приносит некоторые неудобства.